# Pre populate array in knockout using jade

Tags: knockout.js, pug

I have a table of locations on my site, which I would like to be able to be pre-populated using Jade. Normally this would be easy, but as I am using knockout for data binding I don't have a jade iterator, only a knockout one:

```
table.table.table-striped
    thead
        tr
            th Address
            th Coordinates
    tbody(data-bind="foreach: locations")
        tr
            td
                input(data-bind="value: address", placeholder="Address Line 1")
                input(data-bind="value: postalCode", placeholder="Postal Code")
            td
                input(data-bind="value: lat", placeholder="Latitude")
                input(data-bind="value: long", placeholder="Longitude")
            td
                a(data-bind="click: $root.removeLocation") Remove
```

My route passes a store object, which may have multiple locations attached to it:

```
var store = {
    name : "Example Business"
    locations : [
        {
           address : "123 Example Street, Exampleton",
           postalCode : "12345",
           lat : -111.111,
           long : 55.555
        }
    ]
}
```

I assume I can add a `value` to the input that would be e.g. `"#{store.location.address}"` (if store is the object I have passed to jade), but locations is an array. How do I iterate through the multiple existing locations that the store I have on the server side has, without messing up the iteration from knockout?

Comment: Can you show your data locations structure that you get from the server

Comment: @Matt.k Added to the question